# Assignment of local variables causes Audio to stop processing in JUCE

Tags: c++, audio, variable-assignment, local-variables, juce

**EDIT: This turned out to be an uninitialized variable creating chaotic behavior. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891062/how-to-get-compiler-warnings-juce-ubuntu/45894573#45894573) about getting more compiler warnings for JUCE**

I was attempting to create a basic synthesizer and I quickly ran into an absurd problem when simply attempting to assign a value to a newly declared variable.
After following along with the JUCE simple sine synthesis tutorial I ran into the problem. This is the basic code of my `getNextAudioBlock()` function when it is producing white noise. Note how there are four integers declared and assigned throughout:

```
const int numChannels = bufferToFill.buffer->getNumChannels();
const int numSamples = bufferToFill.numSamples;
for (int channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++){
    float* const buffer = bufferToFill.buffer -> getWritePointer(channel, bufferToFill.startSample);
    for (int sample; sample < numSamples; sample++){
        buffer[sample] = (randomGen.nextFloat() * 2.0f - 1.0f);
    }
}
```

However, as soon as I attempt to add another int I no longer get sound. Just simply adding the line `int unusedVariable = 0;` anywhere in the `getNextAudioBlock()` function but before the `buffer[sample]` assignment immediately returns from the function and it therefore produces no audio.

If I simply declare the new variable (`int unusedVariable;`) then it still works. It is only specifically the assignment part that causes the error. Also, if I declare the variable as a global member then the assignment within the function works just fine.

To reiterate, this works:

```
buffer[sample] = (randomGen.nextFloat() * 2.0f - 1.0f;
```

This works:

```
int unusedVariable;
buffer[sample] = (randomGen.nextFloat() * 2.0f - 1.0f;
```

But this doesn't:

```
int unusedVariable = 0;
buffer[sample] = (randomGen.nextFloat() * 2.0f - 1.0f;
```

My only idea was that allocating new memory on the Audio thread causes the error but I have seen declaration and assignment done in other online sources and even in my exact same function with numChannels, numSamples, channel, and sample all allocated and assigned just fine. I also considered that it has something to do with using the Random class, but I get the same problem even when it is generating sine waves.

EDIT: Here is the exact code copied from the project. Right here nextSample is declared globally, as the buffer does not get filled when it is declared locally

```
  void MainContentComponent::getNextAudioBlock (const AudioSourceChannelInfo& bufferToFill)
  {
    const int numChannels = bufferToFill.buffer->getNumChannels();
    const int numSamples = bufferToFill.numSamples;
    for (int channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++){
        float* const buffer = bufferToFill.buffer -> getWritePointer (channel, bufferToFill.startSample);
        for (int sample; sample < numSamples; sample++){
            // nextSample = (randomGen.nextFloat() * 2.0f - 1.0f); // For Randomly generated White Noise
            nextSample = (float) std::sin (currentAngle);
            currentAngle += angleDelta;
            buffer[sample] = nextSample * volumeLevel;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Probably not the solution to your problem, but is condition `numChannels`  in `for (int channel = 0; numChannels; channel++)` intended? It will very likely produce an endless loop.

Comment: sorry, my original code properly says (...; channel < numChannels;...)

Comment: Please paste the real code here. `buffer[sample] = (randomGen.nextFloat() * 2.0f - 1.0f;` won't even compile because of missing closing `)`. Or actually provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added the exact code as well as linked to FirstSynth and AdditiveManual, two projects that only work when the variables are global members

Comment: @brenthompson2 -- if you're a paid licensee and live build is not working for you, you should post on the JUCE forum https://forum.juce.com/, which is monitored by the JUCE development team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new AudioApplication project in the Projucer and pasted this block of code into the `getNextAudioBlock()` method (adding sensible member variables as you're referencing them here).

The compiler pointed at the problem right away -- the loop variable `sample` below isn't initialized (and C++ won't default init it for you), so if the memory used by that variable happened to have contained a value that's less than the buffer size, you'll generate some audio; if not, the buffer passed into this function is unaffected because the loop never runs.

```
    for (int sample; sample < numSamples; sample++){
        nextSample = (randomGen.nextFloat() * 2.0f - 1.0f); // For Randomly generated White Noise
        //nextSample = (float) std::sin (currentAngle);
        //currentAngle += angleDelta;
        buffer[sample] = nextSample * volumeLevel;
    }
```

see if changing that to `for (int sample=0;` doesn't fix things for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes a lot of sense. I will try that in the morning. What compiler were you using?

Comment: Xcode 8, but I'd expect the behavior here to be similarly unpredictable everywhere -- see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value

Comment: This was the solution. It also fixed my problem where audio wasn't outputting to both channels. Now if only [I can figure out how to compile with those warnings on my Ubuntu machine...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891062/how-to-get-compiler-warnings-juce-ubuntu)