# How to get compiler warnings JUCE - Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, gcc-warning, juce

I was recently dealing with [an error that should have easily been realized with a simple compiler warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787191/assignment-of-local-variables-causes-audio-to-stop-processing-in-juce).
**Does anyone know how to get compiler warnings to show up when compiling JUCE projects with `make` on Ubuntu?**

I attempted:

- `make -Wall` from the [gcc/gnu Warning Options docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) -> no change
- `make V=1` as commented in the makefile -> it was verbose, but didn't show the warnings
- Editing the live build settings in the Projucer -> live build doesn't work on Ubuntu

**Edit: Answered by OMGtechy**

To add compiler warnings to the build: edit the Linux Makefile settings in the Exporter tab of the Projucer File Manager (See the picture in his answer). However, I didn't see any "uninitialized variable" warnings until I also ran with the optimization flag `-O2`. Apparently [gcc is bad with that warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705880/gcc-failing-to-warn-of-uninitialized-variable).

Comment: Which build settings did you edit? The live ones will probably have no effect on a make build. Did you notice the build commands change at all? Could be a bug. Also, to the downvoters, in the context of JUCE it's quite clear what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add `-Wall`to your exporter compiler flags, possibly with `-Werror` too. Just adding them to the live build flags will only affect the Projucer's live build feature.

[image: Where to add the compiler flags]

Comment: This did work to apply compiler flags to the build. However, I didn't see any uninitialized variable warnings until I used `-O2` also. Apparently [gcc is bad with that warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705880/gcc-failing-to-warn-of-uninitialized-variable) .